# visual studio 2017 getting angular 6 variables displayed on page

Tags: angular, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have set Angular 6 in my existing project in Visual Studio 2017 using Angular cli.

When I do ng build / serve it all works. When I change the css, it detects the changes and the browser refreshes. So all appears normal/to be working.

However variables are dispalying on the page.

The default Welcome to Angular title looks like this - Welcome to {{ title }}!

If you would like to see certain pages/sections of code let me know and I'll add it to my question.

ts file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'my app title';
}
```

html file:

```
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{ title }}!
  </h1>
```

Comment: done - its just the standard angular cli setup/demo page.

Comment: do you see any errors on terminal or console

Comment: Do you have any browser addons that may block javascript?

Comment: @Sajeetharan no, it bg builds fine and bg serves fine, as as i mentioned css changes are picked up and displayed.

Comment: @user184994 no. i can spin up an angular project outside of visual studio and variables display fine.

Comment: you are asking why you cannot see the variable rendered in visual studio?

Comment: @Sajeetharan yes  - as in when i view the page in my browser it says Welcome to {{ title }}!

Comment: @Pepper Is there any erro on browser console?